# How to know if a user already has a role in an addrole command

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to send an error message saying that the user already has the role if they do in an addrole command.My current command is:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
  name: "addrole",
  description: "adds a role to a member",
  execute: async (message , args) => {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_ROLES")) return message.channel.send("Invalid Permissions")
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    let role = message.mentions.roles.first();
    if (!member)
      return message.reply("Please mention a valid member of this server");
    if (!role) return message.reply("please mention a valid role of this server");

    const highest = message.member.roles.highest;

    if(highest.comparePositionTo(role) <= 0)
    return message.channel.send(`You cannot add roles equal/higher to that member's highest role`)
    
    let addroleembed = new MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(`:white_check_mark: ${role.name} has been added to ${member.user.tag}`)
    .setFooter(`Action performed by ${message.author.tag}`)
    .setColor('77B255')
   addroleembed.setTimestamp();

    member.roles.add(role);
  message.channel.send(addroleembed)

}}
```

I have tried using

```
 if(!message.member.roles.cache.some(r=>[`${role.name}`].includes(r.name)))
```

and

```
 if (member.roles.has(role.id) {
```

But neither of these seem to work, Anyone know the reason behind this? If I can't use either of these methods, Can you suggest me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are so close!

All you need is `cache` when using `has()`

```
member.roles.cache.has(<RoleID>);
```

Learn More [Here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=cache)

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine your two tries.

```
if(message.member.roles.cache.has("role ID") {
    //rest of your code
}
```